# C# Animal Spawner Logic - Advice Required

Tags: c#, logic, unity-game-engine

I have spawners for animals scattered across the terrain in my game. The idea is to have animals spawn only when a player is within range of the spawner but not if there are too many animals in a close range to the spawner. This what I have done so far but now I'm a little stuck. Could anyone give me some guidance as to the following things:

- Are the spawn odds calculated correctly? Will setting two animals for example with spawn chance of 10% and 90% actually make animalA have a 10% chance to spawn and animalB have a 90% chance or is my math wrong?
- Are my radius calculations correct?
- **Most importantly: Can I improve it?**

The code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SpawnableAnimal
{
public string AnimalName;
public float spawnWeight;

public float spawnPercentage;
}

public class AnimalSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxSpawnRadius = 1000.0f;
public float noSpawnRadius = 700.0f;

public GameObject spawnedAnimal;

public SpawnableAnimal[] spawnableAnimals;

void Start () {
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    int randInt = rand.Next(0, 100);

    float startTime = randInt / 100f;
    float repeatTime = randInt / 100f;
    InvokeRepeating("ReadyToSpawn", startTime, (60.0f + repeatTime));
}

void ReadyToSpawn()
{
    Debug.Log("Ready to spawn");
    bool canSpawn = true;

    GameObject[] players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    GameObject[] animals = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Animal");
    for(int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, players[i].transform.position) > maxSpawnRadius)
            canSpawn = false;

        if (Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, players[i].transform.position) < noSpawnRadius)
            canSpawn = false;
    }

    if (players.Length < 1)
        canSpawn = false;

    if (spawnedAnimal != null)
        canSpawn = false;

    if (canSpawn)
        SpawnAnimal();
}

void SpawnAnimal()
{
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    double x = rand.NextDouble();

    var totalWeight = spawnableAnimals.Select(a => a.spawnWeight).Sum();

    for(int i = 0; i < spawnableAnimals.Length; i++)
    {
        float spawnPercentage = spawnableAnimals[i].spawnWeight / totalWeight;

        if(x < spawnPercentage)
        {
            InstantiateAnimal(i);
            return;
        }

        x -= spawnPercentage;
    }
}

void InstantiateAnimal(int animalToSpawn)
{
    if (animalToSpawn != -1)
        spawnedAnimal = GameObject.Find("AnimalManager").GetComponent<AnimalManager>().SpawnAnimal(spawnableAnimals[animalToSpawn].AnimalName, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
    else Debug.Log("No animal to spawn!");
}
```

}

Comment: you should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, these kind of questions are off topic here

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even know about codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, players[i].transform.position)
```

Are these positions in the same space? Does `Vector3.Distance(x, y)` mean `|x - y|`? If so then the calculation looks good to me.

`SpawnAnimal` seems odd. I am not sure what it is doing. If you can explain your thinking behind it then I might understand it.

I would assign a weight to every animal. This number is arbitrary but their relative magnitudes are important. If cats have a weight of 100 and dogs have a weight of 1000 then dogs are 10 times more likely to spawn than a cat.

Aside: why weights and not percentages? If you define cats to have a 10% spawn chance and dogs a 90% spawn chance and then you add gerbils, what percentage is left to assign gerbils? The percentages have to add to 1 so you will have to tweak the percentages of all other animals to make room. If we use weights, with cats at 100 and dogs at 1000, then we can add in gerbils with weight 500 and we know gerbils spawn 5 times more than cats and half as often as dogs — no adjustments required.

Lets assume you generate a random number `x` in `[0,1)` (this can be done with [`NextDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble(v=vs.110).aspx)).

We want to assign an interval in `[0,1)` to each animal which is proportional to their weight. First find the total weight.

```
var totalWeight = spawnableAnimals.Select(a => a.Weight).Sum();
```

From this we can assign a percentage for each animal as `a.Weight / totalWeight`. These percentages add to 1 so you can can distribute these percentages over the interval `[0,1)`. `Pi` is the probability of spawning the animal `Ai` from the indexed set of animals `A` where `0 <= i < n` and `n` is `|A|` (i.e. the number of animals).

```
0.0    0.1    0.2    0.3 …    1.0
 [  P1  )[     P2     )[ …  Pn )
```

Now you just have to determine which interval `x` lies in and that is the animal to spawn. Here is a procedural algorithm to do that.

1. Initialize `A = the set of animals`, `i = 0`, `x = NextDouble()`, `n = |A|`.
2. If `i < n`

   - Then: If `x < Pi`

     - Then: halt and spawn `Ai`.
     - Else:

       1. subtract `Pi` from `x`
       2. increment `i`
       3. goto (2).
   - Else: Halt with no animal to spawn.

The `ith` interval (`0 <= i < n`), where summations are indexed by `0 <= j < i` is:

1. `ΣP(j-1) <= x < ΣP(j-1) + Pi` (see example table)
2. `ΣP(j-1) - ΣP(j-1) <= x - ΣP(j-1) < ΣP(j-1) + Pi - ΣP(j-1)` (subtract `ΣP(j-1)`)
3. `0 <= x - ΣP(j-1) < Pi` (simplify)

   - `x - ΣP(j-1)` is achieved by the accumulative subtraction.
   - `0 <= x` is achieved by `0 <= NextDouble() < 1` and if `x >= Pi` then `x - Pi >= 0` (a loop invariant).
   - Therefore, we only need to test `x < Pi`.

Note: this relies on the random number generator having a uniform distribution.

Comment: I really appreciate answers like this! An answer like this helps me understand and learn new ways to approach these things, rather than just giving me code to copy and paste. I tried to replace the SpawnAnimal method with a new method based on your explanation. Are the adjustments above roughly what you mean?

Comment: @MinganBeyleveld not quite. When I say "Halt" you need to end the algorithm, which means `break` in the loop or `return` from the function or whatever is appropriate. I have also fixed my answer with a couple missing pieces in the algorithm (the bounds check `i < n` and the increment of `i`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I updated the code again (hopefully doing it correctly)?

Comment: @MinganBeyleveld looks good. Make sure `spawnableAnimals[i].spawnWeight / totalWeight` is floating division and not integer division.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division here :

```
float startTime = randInt / 100
```

I think what you want is :

```
float startTime = randInt / 100f
```

You're getting spawn chance "reversed" :

```
if(randInt <= spawnableAnimals[i].spawnChance
```

should be :

```
if(randInt >= spawnableAnimals[i].spawnChance
```

However, that doesn't quite solves it all, because :

```
arraySum += randInt;
```

is doing the same as :

```
break;
```

So, if the first element in spawnableAnimals has a spawnChance of 10%, and the second element in spawnableAnimals has a spawnChance of 90%, you will end up with a distribution of 10% for the first, and 90% * 90% = 81% for the second, because the second element is tried only if the first failed.